# How to replace button by clicking in Javascript

Tags: javascript

When I try to remove element by clicking them. I suffered some trouble.

When I create element and append this to element,previous element was not removed.

My desired result is to replace them to new button.

How can I achieve it?  If you have opinion,please let me know.

thanks

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",function(){
  
      let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
      let button = document.createElement("button");
      button.textContent = 'retry';
      button.className = 'retry';
      
      btn.appendChild(button);

})
```

```html
<div id="btn"><button>test</button></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Node.replaceChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild) method:

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",function(){
  let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
  let button = document.createElement("button");
  button.textContent = 'retry';
  button.className = 'retry';

  btn.parentNode.replaceChild(button, btn);
})
```

```html
<div id="btn"><button>test</button></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to replace the button entirely, you can just update its properties, as shown below.

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.target.innerHTML = 'retry';
    e.target.className = 'retry';
});
```

```html
<div id="btn"><button>test</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",function(){
      let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
      let button = document.createElement("button");
      button.textContent = 'retry';
      button.className = 'retry';
      
      btn.replaceWith(button);

})
```

```html
<div id="btn"><button>test</button></div>
```